# Uninstall different versions of python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda

I made a mistake and installed many different versions of python on my linux machine. I installed all the versions of python with the help of anaconda. My default python version shows 2.7.11.

Now I want to remove all the versions of python and its dependencies from my linux system. What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

Do you use [Virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? If not, you should ;-)
Install with:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Or:

```
apt-get install virtualenv
```

Or any other way package manager you have!
Virtualenv is a program that creates a virtual machine in you computer that works with Python. You can use it to make an isolate environment of working with python and you can choose which version of python you want to use.
This will create a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv myenv
```

And this will create a virtualenv with a specific python version:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 myenv
```

then you can `cd` into it like:

```
cd myenv
```

Then you have something like this:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── activate
│   ├── activate.csh
│   ├── activate.fish
│   ├── activate_this.py
│   ├── easy_install
│   ├── easy_install-3.5
│   ├── pip
│   ├── pip3
│   ├── pip3.5
│   ├── python -> python3.5
│   ├── python3 -> python3.5
│   ├── python3.5
│   ├── python-config
│   └── wheel
├── include
│   └── python3.5m -> /usr/include/python3.5m
└── lib
    └── python3.5
```

and by runnig:

```
. bin/activate
```

your virtualenv will be activated and every `pip` command you run or script you run will use the version of python you used to create the env.

Comment: Actually in my case, I want to work with ruby. So different versions of python are creating hindrance and giving me errors. Now, I just want to clean up my system and start the anaconda installation of python from the beginning.

Comment: In that case, I think `pip uninstall pythonx.x` will help (x.x is the version you want to remove) pip is python package manager.

Comment: Actually, I have not installed pip. So should I first install pip and remove the python versions? remind you that I installed python from anaconda.

Comment: As far as I know. anaconda is for python. not python for anaconda!!! So there should be no problem at all. But if anaconda depends on a certain version of python, you may need to remove and reinstall anaconda.

Answer (score -2):

You can try going to:

> /Library/Python

and manually delete the versions you do not want. This isn't recommended though.